# Getting the last modified time of a directory over HTTP using RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl

Say I want to get the last modified time of a file over HTTP using [rcurl](/questions/tagged/rcurl). I can do the following:

```r
# URL for a specific file
file_url <- "https://dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/25km/grib2/lat_lon/00/000/CMC_glb_ABSV_ISBL_200_latlon.24x.24_2020121500_P000.grib2"

# Use RCurl to get last modified time
RCurl::url.exists(file_url, .header = TRUE)["Last-Modified"]
#>                   Last-Modified 
#> "Tue, 15 Dec 2020 03:51:51 GMT"
```

Bonza! That works perfectly. Now, say I want to do the same, but for a *directory*.

```r
# URL for a directory
dir_url <- "https://dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/25km/grib2/lat_lon/00/000"

# Use RCurl to get last modified time
RCurl::url.exists(dir_url, .header = TRUE)["Last-Modified"]
#> <NA> 
#>   NA
```

This clearly doesn't work; however, there *is* a last modified date associated with the folder:

[image]

Presumably, files and folders are treated differently. It's not clear to me how I can extract the last modified time using this approach. Is this possible with [rcurl](/questions/tagged/rcurl)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option using `rvest` with some html parsing:

```r
library(rvest)

url <- "https://dd.weather.gc.ca/model_gem_global/25km/grib2/lat_lon/00/"

df <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//pre") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  strsplit("\n") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  strsplit(" {2,100}") %>%
  `[`(-1) %>%
  {do.call(rbind, .)} %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("Folder", "Modified", "Size"))
```

Giving us:

```
df
#>    Folder         Modified Size
#> 1    000/ 2020-12-15 03:52    -
#> 2    003/ 2020-12-15 03:56    -
#> 3    006/ 2020-12-15 03:56    -
#> 4    009/ 2020-12-15 03:57    -
#> 5    012/ 2020-12-15 03:57    -
#> 6    015/ 2020-12-15 03:59    -
#> 7    018/ 2020-12-15 03:59    -
#> 8    021/ 2020-12-15 03:59    -
#> 9    024/ 2020-12-15 03:59    -
#> 10   027/ 2020-12-15 04:01    -
#> 11   030/ 2020-12-15 04:01    -
#> 12   033/ 2020-12-15 04:03    -
#> 13   036/ 2020-12-15 04:03    -
#> 14   039/ 2020-12-15 04:03    -
#> 15   042/ 2020-12-15 04:03    -
#> 16   045/ 2020-12-15 04:03    -
#> 17   048/ 2020-12-15 04:04    -
#> 18   051/ 2020-12-15 04:05    -
#> 19   054/ 2020-12-15 04:06    -
#> 20   057/ 2020-12-15 04:06    -
#> 21   060/ 2020-12-15 04:06    -
#> 22   063/ 2020-12-15 04:08    -
#> 23   066/ 2020-12-15 04:08    -
#> 24   069/ 2020-12-15 04:09    -
#> 25   072/ 2020-12-15 04:09    -
#> 26   075/ 2020-12-15 04:09    -
#> 27   078/ 2020-12-15 04:10    -
#> 28   081/ 2020-12-15 04:11    -
#> 29   084/ 2020-12-15 04:12    -
#> 30   087/ 2020-12-15 04:13    -
#> 31   090/ 2020-12-15 04:14    -
#> 32   093/ 2020-12-15 04:13    -
#> 33   096/ 2020-12-15 04:14    -
#> 34   099/ 2020-12-15 04:15    -
#> 35   102/ 2020-12-15 04:18    -
#> 36   105/ 2020-12-15 04:19    -
#> 37   108/ 2020-12-15 04:19    -
#> 38   111/ 2020-12-15 04:19    -
#> 39   114/ 2020-12-15 04:20    -
#> 40   117/ 2020-12-15 04:20    -
#> 41   120/ 2020-12-15 04:20    -
#> 42   123/ 2020-12-15 04:20    -
#> 43   126/ 2020-12-15 04:20    -
#> 44   129/ 2020-12-15 04:21    -
#> 45   132/ 2020-12-15 04:22    -
#> 46   135/ 2020-12-15 04:23    -
#> 47   138/ 2020-12-15 04:23    -
#> 48   141/ 2020-12-15 04:22    -
#> 49   144/ 2020-12-15 04:22    -
#> 50   147/ 2020-12-15 04:21    -
#> 51   150/ 2020-12-15 04:22    -
#> 52   153/ 2020-12-15 04:23    -
#> 53   156/ 2020-12-15 04:23    -
#> 54   159/ 2020-12-15 04:24    -
#> 55   162/ 2020-12-15 04:25    -
#> 56   165/ 2020-12-15 04:25    -
#> 57   168/ 2020-12-15 04:26    -
#> 58   171/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 59   174/ 2020-12-15 04:30    -
#> 60   177/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 61   180/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 62   183/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 63   186/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 64   189/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 65   192/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 66   195/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 67   198/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 68   201/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 69   204/ 2020-12-15 04:29    -
#> 70   207/ 2020-12-15 04:30    -
#> 71   210/ 2020-12-15 04:31    -
#> 72   213/ 2020-12-15 04:32    -
#> 73   216/ 2020-12-15 04:32    -
#> 74   219/ 2020-12-15 04:33    -
#> 75   222/ 2020-12-15 04:34    -
#> 76   225/ 2020-12-15 04:34    -
#> 77   228/ 2020-12-15 04:36    -
#> 78   231/ 2020-12-15 04:41    -
#> 79   234/ 2020-12-15 04:41    -
#> 80   237/ 2020-12-15 04:41    -
#> 81   240/ 2020-12-15 04:41    -
```

Comment: Thanks, Allan! I'm surprised that there isn't a more straightforward curl approach, as it must be a fairly common task. I'll leave this open for a few days to see if there are any other solutions.